# Server design for social app

Tags: database

I am currently designing an app to upload and download files from a server.  I want to know what type of server to implement that would be robust enough to handle a lot of data per user and a lot of users.

I realise this is probably a very broad and slightly naive question.

I have done some research I think I have to get a SQL server and create a web service for the database and implement a REST system for interfacing with the service on the device side.

Regards, J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a naive question per se, but you need to provide way more information than that.

If you just like to transfer files: Why not go with the simple, but effective FTP-protocol?

Comment: I suppose my question was also a little vague.  The files are not the only information that is being passed. The files also have to be shared with other users so I also have some permissions

Comment: ......5 minute rule.........I suppose my question was also a little vague.  The files are not the only information that is being passed there will also be some key value pairs. The files also have to be shared with other users so I also have some permissions.       Is it possible to have a very large amount say a million small tables within the server to act as folders for the files.         I am finding it difficult to wrap my head around having the system robust and scalable enough to handle the large amounts of user in the current market.

Comment: Well, the approach with a lot of small tables is possible, but not very efficient from a performance-perspective.
You should have 1 Table with all the indexs for the Files - if you set the indexes on the right rows, you'll get very fast answers from your sql-server.
Secondly: Do not pack all files into 1 folder: Instead, use a good and automated folder-structure. You'll get better performance with 10'000 Files in 5 Folders than 50'000 Files in one Folder (maybe depends on the filesystem, I only know it for NTFS).
Permission and Membership can be done with your APP or as an Hybride with the OS